# How to remove certain elements from the inner array in JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, arrays

var array = [[10, 20, 30, 20, 50], [40, 50, 60, 20, 20], [70, 80, 90, 20, 20], [70, 80, 90, 20, 20]];

For example i want to delete elements == 50

I want this result -> array= [[10,30,20], [40,60,20], [70,90,20], [70,90,20]];

I try this solution but it is not working ->

```
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] == 50) {
        array[i].splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please don't create new users to ask the same question [How to delete multidimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71206891/215552) was closed earlier.

Comment: What is not working? I tried here on Firefox, it's working and removing the 50 from the array.. only 50.

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto, `splice` is changing the length and index. for example the next index is never checked.

Comment: btw, why are some `20` values missing in the result?

Comment: I want to delete same index   for example if array[0][1] == 50 i want to delete all array[i][0] @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect unwanted indices first and then return.

```js
const
    data = [
        [10, 20, 30, 20, 50], 
        [40, 50, 60, 20, 20], 
        [70, 80, 90, 20, 20], 
        [70, 80, 90, 20, 20]
    ],
    //       ^^          ^^ cols with 50
    //
    indices = data.reduce(
        (r, a) => a.map((v, i) => v === 50 ? false : r[i] ?? true),
        []
    ),
    result = data.map(a => a.filter((_, i) => indices[i]));

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [[10, 20, 30, 20, 50], [40, 50, 60, 20, 20], [70, 80, 90, 20, 20], [70, 80, 90, 20, 20]];


const filteredArr = array.map(item => [...new Set(item.filter(i => i !== 50))])

// filterdArr = [[10, 30, 20], [40, 60, 20], [70, 80, 90, 20], [70, 80, 90, 20]];
```